# Comparing nested list with dictionary keys, create compound key 'a+b' with sum of values

Tags: python

I have a nested list and I want to compare list items with dictionary keys and if match is found the corresponding dictionary values should be summed and appended to same dictionary as new key-value pair.

```
l1 = [['a','b'], ['c','d']] 

dict1 = {'a':10, 'e':20, 'c':30, 'b':40}
```

Expected result:

```
dict1 = {'a':10, 'e':20, 'c':30, 'b':40, 'a+b':50, 'a+c':40, 'b+c':70}
```

What I have done so far:

```
for x in range(len(l1)):
    for y in range(len(l1[x])):
        for k in dict1.keys():
            if k == l1[x][y]:
                dict1.append(dict1[k])
```

Is there any way to do this without using nested for loops?
PS: code is not complete yet.

Comment: Why is that your expected output? Why no e.g. `c+d`?

Comment: @tomjn because list item 'd' is not present in dictionary keys..

Comment: Sorry I was being stupid that makes sense. At the risk of another stupid question, do the sub lists in `l1` have any special meaning?

Comment: Your l1 seems wrong, the nested aspect is irrelevant. Are we simply supposed to take every valid (1-) or 2-element permutation from all the (flattened) elements of l1? and ignore invalid keys like 'd'?

Comment: @smci in the original code l1 is being appended by some other logic and sub lists have their own meaning.. The sub lists are being used in other section of code.. The idea is to compare sub list items with dictionary keys and if match is found add the corresponding dict values and append into same dictionary(without ignoring keys which are not available in sub lists) I hope it is clear now

Comment: But that only explains why the compound key 'a+b' should get created, it doesn't explain why either of 'a+c' or 'b+c' should? (only that it might try to create 'c+d', find that 'd' is invalid, and stop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming there is no importance to your nested lists e.g. `l1` can be changed to `["a", "b", "c", d"]` you can use [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) here.

First flatten `l1` with `itertools.chain`

```
import itertools
l2 = itertools.chain(*l1)
```

(or `l2 = itertools.chain.from_iterable(l1)`).

Then loop through all combinations of two elements

```
for i, j in itertools.combinations(l2, 2):
    if i in dict1 and j in dict1:
        dict1[f"{i}+{j}"] = dict1[i] + dict1[j]
```

All together

```py
import itertools 

l1 = [['a','b'], ['c','d']] 
dict1 = {'a':10, 'e':20, 'c':30, 'b':40}
 
for i, j in itertools.combinations(itertools.chain(*l1), 2):
    if i in dict1 and j in dict1:
        dict1[f"{i}+{j}"] = dict1[i] + dict1[j]
```

`dict1` will now equal

```
{'a': 10, 'e': 20, 'c': 30, 'b': 40, 'a+b': 50, 'a+c': 40, 'b+c': 70}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Now its working as expected.

Comment: There is a small change in the question.. What if the nested list consists of more than 2 elements.. like `l1 = [['a','b'], ['c','d'], ['e','f','g']]` and `dict1 = {'a':10, 'e':20, 'c':30, 'b':40, 'f':10, 'g':20}` List is appended by some logic and number of elements inside nested list is not fixed.. Can you please let me know how to find compound key in this case..

Comment: Hi @Sourabh, you should ask a new follow up question. It is not clear what you want to change here and why the existing solution doesn't work?

Comment: Hi @tomjn, existing solution works perfectly.. but now I want to know what happens if sublist elements are more than 2.. for example l1 is like `l1 = [['a','b'], ['c','d'], ['e','f','g']]` now the expected result is `dict1 = {'a':10, 'e':20, 'c':30, 'b':40, 'a+b':50, 'a+c':40, 'e+f+g':50, 'b+c':70}` How the logic will change to add 3 elements?

Comment: I think you should ask a new question because it isn't clear to me what the requirements are here. For example, why isn't there a+b+c or a+b+f whereas you do have a+c?

Comment: I have asked a new question.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68119311/comparing-nested-list-with-dictionary-keys-and-create-compound-key-value-pair  Please let me know if its still unclear..

Answer (score 0):

you can try the below code

```
dict1 = {'a':10, 'e':20, 'c':30, 'b':40, 'a+b':50, 'a+c':40, 'b+c':70}
dict2={}
dict2['a+b']=dict1['a']+dict1['b']
dict2['a+c']=dict1['a']+dict1['c']
dict2['b+c']=dict1['b']+dict1['c']
dict1.update(dict2)
print(dict1)
```

Comment: This is just hardwiring terms like 'a+b'. It will break on arbitrary input.

Comment: yes , the code is according to the o/p, I found it simple with out using the loop .

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following, using generators:

NOTE: OP if you don't clarify the question I'll delete this

```
d = {'a':10, 'e':20, 'c':30, 'b':40}
l1 = [['a','b'], ['c','d']]

def _gen_compound_keys(d, kk):
    """Generator helper function for the single and ocmpound keys from input tuple of keys"""
    # Note: you can trivially generalize this from assuming fixed length of 2
    yield kk[0], d[kk[0]]
    yield kk[1], d[kk[1]]
    yield '+'.join(kk), sum(d[k] for k in kk)

def gen_compound_keys(d, kk):
    """Generator for the single and compound keys, returns a dictionary as desired"""
    return {k:v for k,v in _gen_compound_keys(d, kk)}

result = {}
result.update(gen_compound_keys(d, l1[0]))
result.update(gen_compound_keys(d, l1[1]))
result.update(d)
```